# Rails 3.1 + Bootstrap 2 + less

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, less, twitter-bootstrap

For adding Bootstrap framework to my app in Rails 3.1 I use the gem

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '~> 1.3.0'
```

and in my CSS file I import Bootstraps`s CSS data

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap";
```

Is already an update for new version Bootstrap 2? I guess is still soon to ask, but because I currently play with this nice CSS framework, so I am trying to update to its new version...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails was recently updated to v2 stable.

Comment: I tried this a while ago and that don't support new Bootstrap v2. When I open the `bootstrap.css`, so there is still the last version, not new.

Comment: Btw., there are generated two bootstrap files - `<link href="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and `<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and both have the same content.

Comment: As of Feb 2, it doesn't include all of the v2 features.  It appears close, though.

Comment: twitter-bootstrap-rails completely supporting v2 stable, including generators.

Answer (score 3):

From the less-rails-bootstrap documentation:

"This gem will directly track the semantic versioning releases of the Twitter Bootstrap project. Our major and minor versions will always match to theirs. Tho we may have tiny patch level releases specific to this gem."

The current release is 2.0.2. You're using the pessimistic version constraint "~> 1.3.0", you want "~> 2.0".

You don't need the @import statement, since that is done for you by the gem. Doing both is why you have two copies of the same generated bootstrap files.

Comment: I can confirm that less-rails-bootstrap is updated to v2.  Just today I updated one of my projects.